# Riemann Siegel function and gamma function

Tags: zeta-functions

I ask about an  idea to prove this formula:

$Γ(1/2-iβ)=((\sqrt{π})/(\sqrt{\coshπβ}))\exp(-i(2ϑ(β)+βln2π+\arctan(\tanh(1/2)πβ)))$

where $ϑ(β)$ is the Riemann Siegel function.

Comment: I'm curious about this unusual phenomenon (yet expected, by the "Reversal" badge)  of +15 points difference between question and answer! Some hints?

Comment: @PietroMajer: Myabe the question is very trivial and you can see that the answer is not trivial!!.

Comment: Yes, but if a question originates a non trivial and interesting answer, it shouldn't be that bad. Anyway, I  respect your sportsman-like attitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know two proof, the first uses 
$$\cos\frac{\pi s}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\cosh(\pi
t)}\,e^{-i\arctan(\tanh\frac{\pi t}{2})}.\qquad (1)$$
and 
$$\Gamma(\frac12+i\frac t 2)=|\Gamma(\frac14+i\frac t2)|\,e^{i(\vartheta(t)+\frac t 2\log\pi)},\qquad (2)$$

Since 
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)=2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2z);\quad
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$$
we get
$$\Gamma(2z)=2^{2z-1}\pi^{-1/2} \Gamma(z)\frac{\pi}{\cos\pi
z}\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2-z)}.$$
We put now $z=\frac14+i\frac t 2$, $t$  real
$$
\Gamma(\frac12+it)=2^{-\frac12+it}\frac{\pi^{\frac12}}{\cos\pi(\frac14+i\frac{t}{2})}
\frac{\Gamma(\frac14+i\frac{t}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac14-i\frac{t}{2})}.
$$
From (1) and (2) we get
$$\Gamma(1/2+it)=2^{it}\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{\sqrt{\cosh \pi t}\; e^{-i
\arctan\tanh(\pi t/2)}}\pi^{it} e^{2i\vartheta(t)}.
$$
so that
$$
\Gamma(1/2+it)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\cosh\pi
t}}\exp\bigl\{i(2\vartheta(t)+t\log(2\pi)+\arctan\tanh(\pi
t/2))\bigr\}
$$

The other proof I know uses the functional equation of the zeta function.

Comment: @Juan: Note that all the identities concerning arguments holds only modulo factors of 2π  if the argument is being restricted to (−π,π] . How you can deal with arguments figured in this proof. This is a problem since these arguments depend on the variable t .

Comment: @RH The argument of $\Gamma(s)$ is well defined and harmonic on the plane with a 
cut along the negative real axis.  

Answer (score 1):

I extended juan's proof to a formula for all complex numbers.

Consequently, we get the Euler chi function $\chi(z):=\zeta(1-z)/\zeta(z)$.

(**substitution**)

$\tan^{-1}(\tanh(\pi t/2))\longrightarrow\frac{\mathrm{gd}(\pi t)}2$, where $\mathrm{gd}(z)$ is the Gudermannian function.

$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi t)}}\longrightarrow\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\cosh(\pi t)}\left(\sinh(\frac{\pi t}2)\sin(\frac{\mathrm{gd}(\pi t)}{2})+\cosh(\frac{\pi t}{2})\cos(\frac{\mathrm{gd}(\pi t)}2)\right)$

$t\longrightarrow z$

(**simplification**) If we covert the above result(trigonometric functions) to exponentials, then we get the following simplified formula.

$\Gamma(\frac12+iz)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(1+i)(2\pi)^{iz}}{e^{\pi z}+i}e^{\frac{\pi z}2+2i\vartheta(z)}/;z\in\mathbb{C}$

Therefore,

$\Gamma(z)=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{1+e^{i\pi z}}e^{i(2\vartheta(\frac{i}2-iz)+\frac{\pi z}2)}=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{2\cos(\frac{\pi z}2)}e^{2i\vartheta(\frac{i}2-iz)}=\frac{(2\pi)^z}{2\cos(\frac{\pi z}2)}\chi(z)$

Comment: @ Sangkyu Kim: But the gamma function has no closed form.

Comment: @ Sangkyu Kim: It has no an explicit formula.

Comment: @China-HongKong So do you mean his answer is somewhere wrong?

Comment: What is Euler chi function?

Comment: How do you prove that $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi t)}}\longrightarrow\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\cosh(\pi t)}\left(\sinh(\frac{\pi t}2)\sin(\frac{\mathrm{gd}(\pi t)}{2})+\cosh(\frac{\pi t}{2})\cos(\frac{\mathrm{gd}(\pi t)}2)\right)$
?

Comment: @China-HongKong Since $\chi(z)$ doesn't have explicit formula his answer did not show that Gamma function has a closed form.